# Scan automation with PowerShell and WIA - How to set PNG as image type

Tags: powershell-2.0, windows-7-x64, wia

**What I have:** I'm using PowerShell 2.0 and [WIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368(v=vs.85).aspx) to quickly scan and save an image from my flatbed scanner. The goal was to avoid all dialogs, just a single click. This code is simple, short and works.

```
$deviceManager = new-object -ComObject WIA.DeviceManager
$device = $deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Item(1).Connect()    

foreach ($item in $device.Items) { 
    $image = $item.Transfer() 
}    

$image.SaveFile("D:\Scan.$($image.fileExtension)")
```

**Problem:** The method above always produces BMP files. But I wanted PNG files instead.

I saw this [C# code which uses another WIA method](http://stepsix.org/2010/03/31/an-intro-to-wia-windows-image-acquisition-in-c-part-1/) where the user was able to pass some arguments to the scan dialog like PNG as file format

Now I wonder if and how it's possible to achieve the same only with PowerShell

---

#### I found most of the code here

- http://deletethis.net/dave/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcerealnumber.livejournal.com%2F47638.html
- http://ardalis.com/powershell-control-over-nikon-d3000-camera
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630806(v=vs.85).aspx

<sub>PS: Just in case your solution involves the 'Take Picture' command (wiaCommandTakePicture). Unfortunalty my CanoScan LIDE 210 doesn't support that command</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the FormatID string argument to the Transfer method. The list of available formats is available in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, there's a catch. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557430/wias-showacquireimage-only-saves-in-bmp), the Transfer method doesn't have to observe the requested format, and the output must be converted manually in that case. By converting the [MSDN's VB example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630826(v=VS.85).aspx#SharedSample002) to PowerShell we get this (works on my machine with my scanner):

```
$deviceManager = new-object -ComObject WIA.DeviceManager
$device = $deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Item(1).Connect()    

$wiaFormatPNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
foreach ($item in $device.Items) { 
    $image = $item.Transfer($wiaFormatPNG) 
}    

if($image.FormatID -ne $wiaFormatPNG)
{
    $imageProcess = new-object -ComObject WIA.ImageProcess
    $imageProcess.Filters.Add($imageProcess.FilterInfos.Item("Convert").FilterID)
    $imageProcess.Filters.Item(1).Properties.Item("FormatID").Value = $wiaFormatPNG
    $image = $imageProcess.Apply($image)
}

$image.SaveFile("C:/my_full_path/test.png")
```

Comment: Can I change image properties like height, width, pixel depth and most important the compression level if I use jpg instead of png? Currently I use a *trick* with `RotateNoneFlipNone` to compress jpg images. ([see code snipped](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/48db9a9525e5f4523eb8))

Comment: Yes, I believe so. JPEG conversion example with quality setting is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630819(v=vs.85).aspx#FilterSharedSample016), and more other examples to use filters are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630819(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: should i close device after connect or transfer or the wia subsystem cares about it automatically? my scanner start to behave strange after several launches of this script.